# OOP - Inheritance

Tags: oop, class

If I have a class, class Animal.

And I have a class Dog and a class Cat both inheriting Animal.

Cat can call methods inside Animal. But can Cat call methods of Dog?

Comment: @DWright, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class   ;)

Comment: So, it would not work unless you explicitly do `friend class Dog`?

Comment: @stackplasm, yes.  You could also cast Cat and Dogs to each other, but that opens up all sorts of potential problems . . .

Comment: Why do you want it to work? I wouldn't.  Making a cat be a dog indicates that inheritance is the wrong mechanism. Friend is a hack, last resort not first.

Comment: In javascript yes , depends on the language, trully.

Comment: Yeah, the whole friends mechanism would only work in C++, and I totally agree that it should be a last resort.

Comment: You could of course have an Interface of ICommonHouseholdPet, and have the interface sketch some functionality that you think Cats and Dogs should share, but not all Animals. But that's Java-ish . .  . What language are we talking here?  In Java this would be an interface.  In C++ you could do multiple inheritance.  In Scala you do a trait.  So language matters.  More what matters more so: what do want to achieve.  If you add detail, you'll get more targeted OOP advice.  And it's a good question to be asking, because good inheritance/composition choices are almost the entire battle in OOP.

Comment: @camus Some people would argue JavaScript is not OOP :)

Comment: @PeeHaa, that's the prototype :-] of a Javascript intolerant answer.

Comment: @PeeHaa , well OOP is a paradigm and in my opinion javascript has all the tools to implement that paradigm. Does it make it easy to do OOP ? that's another question , but you can definetly create objects with states and behavior , instanciate them , use polymorphism , encapsulate methods , ect ...

Comment: @stackplasm which language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods defined in a superclass are accesible to any subclass. But "sister" classes cannot access the (private) methods of one another.

So if your classes `Cat` and `Dog` inherit from `Animal`, then both `Cat` and `Dog` objects can call methods from `Animal`, but they cannot (*must not*) access the methods of each other.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question can be answered by stating it like this
Is a cat a dog?

I'll let you answer this one.

Comment: +1 - I frequently find that oo questions can be resolved quite easily when framed in terms of the (English) language. A classic example is "is a" versus "has a".

Comment: It's the first question you should ask. Followed by it's near relative you ask last, Is a cat still a cat?

Comment: Speaking about domain terms and their relationships in natural language, that's what OOP was invented for!

Answer (score 3):

No it can not and no it should not (at least not when talking about proper OOP). If a cat really needs a dog (for whatever sick reason) you should inject the dog in the cat. If you think you need it you probably have the wrong inheritance / abstraction.

```
class Animal
{
    public annoy();
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
    private $dog;

    public function __construct(Dog $dog)
    {
        $this->dog = $dog;
    }

    public function annoyDog()
    {
        $this->dog->annoy();
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
}

$dog = new Dog();
$cat = new Cat($dog);
$cat->annoyDog();
```

Above is an example of injection. Note that as Tony Hopkinson stated you are calling the methods on the instance of dog in this case. You could call methods on the class if they are `public static`, but since it is tagged OOP you really shouldn't. P.S. example is in PHP.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "inject"?

Comment: If you passed an istance of dog to cat. Cat would still not be calling dogs methods, they would be called on the dog you passed in.

Comment: @Barranka: Inject means something like "flexibly configure with another object from the outside".  The term comes from **Dependency Injection**, which is worth googling for more info.

Comment: @Barranka Related: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=RlfLCWKxHJ0. Actually the entire Clean code series is pretty good: http://www.g-truc.net/post-0182.html

Comment: Ther's no rul that the only thing you can inject into a class is a dependency, so no inject does not mean DI

Comment: Inject a dog into a cat? *Visualizing*... disgusting! *SCNR* :)
+1 for mentioning wrong inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

```
If I have a class, class Animal.

And I have a class Dog and a class Cat both inheriting Animal.

Cat can call methods inside Animal. But can Cat call methods of Dog?
```

in javascript , yes , i'll use coffeescript because it is easier to write :

```
class Animal
   bark:-> "i'm an animal"

class Dog extends Animal
  eatBone : -> "i'm eating a bone"

class Cat extends Animal

cat = new Cat

alert Dog::eatBone.call cat
```

Does it make sense ? probably not, but in javascript methods of a prototype are not bound to an object(unless you force it with closures). Now one could argue javascript doesnt have classes like java , but are C++ classes like Java ones ? python classes like Java ones ? who decides what's a real class or not ?

My point is the question is irrelevant outside of a language context.

Answer (score 1):

Here cat and dog are two distinct classes and there is no direct relation between them.If we wish we can add few codes to link these classes. Until then the members in one cannot be accessed from the other.

Answer (score 0):

If Cat doesn't inherit from Dog then no

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that... no. `Cat` cannon invoke `Dog` methods.

Inheritance allows to "view" parents (`public`/`protected` if you are using Java) methods inside child classes, but not inside siblings classes.

Obviosly if `Cat` has an instance of `Dog` as property (I don't know why it should have...) it can call `public` methods of that `Dog` instance.

Answer (score 0):

In java context [I have come across OOPs via Java]

No you cannot.

The methods that can be called by an object is determined by the reference variable.

If you use Dog/Cat reference variable it can only access methods in Dog/Cat class(including inherited and overridden ones)

If you use Animal(i.e.Parent Class) as a reference variable and have it refer to a Cat/Dog class object. You can only call the inherited/overridden methods of subclass using that reference variable.This is decided at compile time.[if the fn being called is identified by the reference variable or no]

The Dog class object is unaware of exclusive Cat class functions[other than inherited and overridden ones] so it cant call the methods.

As pointed by others, If u have a case as such u might not be looking for inheritance.