# What is the function of super() in phaser frameworks?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make a very basic game in Javascript using the Phaser Directory. Now I found two different ways to start building the game:

```
  class Game extends Phaser.Game {
constructor() {
  super(800, 800, Phaser.AUTO, 'game-container');

  this.state.add('Boot',         Boot);
  this.state.add('Preload',      Preload);
  this.state.add('Menu',         Menu);
  this.state.add('SelectMap',    SelectMap);

  this.state.start('Boot');

   }
}

new Game();
```

and the second one:

```
function () {
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 450, Phaser.AUTO, 'gameContainer', null, false, false);

game.state.add('Boot',          Boot);
game.state.add('Preload',       Preload);
game.state.add('Menu',          Menu);
game.state.add('Game',          Game);

    game.state.start('Boot')
}
```

I'm able to understand how the second one works, but in the first one there is this part that I don't understand:

```
super(800, 800, Phaser.AUTO, 'game-container');
```

Can someone please explain me this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: What's the difference between .call() and super()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034059/javascript-whats-the-difference-between-call-and-super)

Comment: @Phix Thank you for the reference!

Comment: @c69 I just read the post you mentioned and yeah the question is similar with mine

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature of ES2015. `super()` calls the constructor of the super class, in this case `Phaser.Game`. Note that this syntax is not specific to Phaser Framework but is a new feature in more recent versions of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

it's the principle of inheritance. The `super()`method is the construct of the parent in the first one the parent is `Phraser.Game`

I can read this : https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

`super()` for **super class** as in several other programming languages such as JAVA, is a method that is used to call an object's parent. Being said, you will have access to the parent's functions as well.

To be able to fully understand this, you will need to understand the concept of object inheritance as a part of Object Oriented Programming (OOP) paradigm. This may help you: [OOP - Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491186/oop-inheritance)

Now more on the subject, this line:

```
super(800, 800, Phaser.AUTO, 'game-container');
```

How it works? `Phaser.Game` inherits from `Phaser` that means that `Phaser.Game` will inherit all the attributes from `Phaser`. And such, we will have to initialize all the attributes that are in `Phaser` once again. Instead, we will actually call for the constructor of the parent class, that being `Phaser`and let it do that for us. Then we will initialize the new attributes of `Phaser.Game`.

Note that this method is not limited to Phaser only but it is a part of Javascript.
A quick search on google will prompt you the following:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super